# ¿Cómo introducir sys.argv a este código?

Tags: python

```
fil1= int(input("Introduce el número de filas de la matriz 1: "))
col1= int(input("Introduce el número de columnas de la matriz 1: "))
fil2= int(input("Introduce el número de filas de la matriz 2: "))
col2= int(input("Introduce el número de columnas de la matriz 2: "))
```

**¿Cómo hago para que en vez de que le pida al usuario uno por uno los datos, mediante un sys.argv pueda introducir los valores seguidos desde el cmd?**

**"Si les sirve el código completo obvio puedo subirlo"**

Comment: ¿Como quieres que se introduzcan exactamente simplemente algo como `$python script.py 4 7 5 13`?

Comment: Exactamente, que los valores se introduzcan así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.args` retorna una lista dónde `argv [0]` es el nombre del script o `"-c"` si se ejecuta el script con el comando `-c` del intérprete. El resto de items de la lista son los argumentos en forma de cadenas `str` Si el comando se ejecutó utilizando la opción de línea de comando -c para el intérprete, argv [0] se establece en la cadena '-c'. Si no se pasó ningún nombre de script al intérprete de Python, argv [0] es la cadena vacía.

Por lo tanto lo único que debes es convertir en enteros los items de la lista, saltándote el primero. No obstante es recomendable que valides la entrada y generes un mensaje informativo si algo no es correcto:

```
import sys


if len(sys.argv) != 5:
    print("Numero de argumentos incorrecto")
    print(f"Uso: python {sys.argv[0]} filas_m1 columnas_m1 filas_m2 columnas_m2")
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    fil1, col1, fil2, col2 = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
except ValueError:
    print("Todos los argumentos deben ser enteros")
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    if any(n <= 0 for n in (fil1, col1, fil2, col2)):
        print("Todos los argumentos deben ser mayores de 0")
        sys.exit(1)
```

`sys.argv` es muy básico, si quieres algo más avanzado que permita mayor facilidad para la validación o el uso de argumentos opcionales, ayuda, etc usa `argparse`:

```
import argparse



def int_mayor_de_cero(value):
    n = int(value)
    if n <= 0:
        raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
            f"{value} no es un entero positivo mayor que 0")
    return n

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Operaciones con matrices')
parser.add_argument(
    'fil1', metavar='FILAS1', type=int_mayor_de_cero,
    help='Número de filas de la primera matriz'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    'col1', metavar='COLS1', type=int_mayor_de_cero,
    help='Número de columnas de la primera matriz'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    'fil2', metavar='FILAS2', type=int_mayor_de_cero,
    help='Número de filas de la segunda matriz'
    )
parser.add_argument(
    'col2', metavar='COLS2', type=int_mayor_de_cero,
    help='Número de columnas de la segunda matriz'
    )

args = parser.parse_args()
fil1, col1, fil2, col2 = args.fil1, args.col1, args.fil2, args.col2
```

> ```
> $ python matrices.py 5 7
> usage: matrices.py [-h] FILAS1 COLS1 FILAS2 COLS2
> matrices.py: error: the following arguments are required: FILAS2, COLS2
>
> $ python matrices.py 4 5 0 7
> usage: matrices.py [-h] FILAS1 COLS1 FILAS2 COLS2
> matrices.py: error: argument FILAS2: 0 no es un entero positivo mayor que 0
>
> $ python matrices.py --help
> usage: main.py [-h] FILAS1 COLS1 FILAS2 COLS2
>
> Operaciones con matrices
>
> positional arguments:
>   FILAS1      Número de filas de la primera matriz
>   COLS1       Número de columnas de la primera matriz
>   FILAS2      Número de filas de la segunda matriz
>   COLS2       Número de columnas de la segunda matriz
>
> optional arguments:
>   -h, --help  show this help message and exit
> ```